# Hide/Remove Item Content Type from a SP List in SPFx

Tags: content-type, 2016, spfx, spfx-webparts

I am using SPFx webpart on SP2016 and able to create a list with custom content type,below is code sample. But I am not able to get any end point to remove default Item content Type. I want my custom content type should be the default one.

```
  public addContentTypeToList(listTitle: string, contentTypeId: string): Promise<ISPBaseResponse> {
    if (!SPUtility.isStringNullOrEmpty(contentTypeId)) {
        try {
            return this.spQueryPOST({
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    "contentTypeId": contentTypeId
                }),
                url: 

`${this.WebUrl}/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('${listTitle}')//ContentTypes/AddAvailableContentType`
            }).then((response) => {
                return response;
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your time and any help.

Regards,